# Images downloaded from s3, how to save them

Tags: html, image, ionic-framework, amazon-s3, mobile-application

After downloading an image from s3, I get a bunch of bits inside the 'Body'. Previously, I was encoding such bits into base64 and displaying them directly in a `<img>` tag.

But now, I want to save them into a "real" file (.jpg/png) in the filesystem (android/iOS) then give the path to a html (background) tag.

> (will it work?)

Do I still need to convert the bunch of bits I got from S3 into base64 then save it or is there a more straightforward way ?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use the plugin cordova-plugin-file for saving file  locally to your filesystem.

Like this
var url = url;
    var targetPath = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + NAME;
    //alert(targetPath);
    var trustHosts = true;
    var options = {};

$cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)

I think you can give the local file address to img src..
```